kubernetes getting mysql error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
I'm new to Kubernetes and am trying to deploy my first application locally using minikube.  My application needs to connect to a mysql database.  Every time I run my deployment yaml I try to access mysql using kubectl exec --stdin --tty <Name of pod> -- /bin/bash and then mysql -u root -padmn -P3306 I get the error ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).  I thought that I maybe had something wrong in my yaml files, but after a lot of searching on the internet, it was suggested that because I had a local installation of mysql on my computer that this might cause an issue.  So I started a Ubuntu VM and ran my yaml files there and everything worked.  So I removed mysql from my local (linux Mint), following the instruction posted here https://askubuntu.com/questions/640899/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql-completely, and tried again.  Still the same thing.  Does anyone know why this is happening?  How I can fix it.  The only thing I can find on the internet about this error has to do with local installation and not through kubernetes, so the fixes don't work.  Please let me know if you need me to provide any additional information.
Edit I am including my yaml files below.
My mysql-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:8.0
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mysql-config
              key: MYSQL_DB_NAME
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mysql-config
              key: MYSQL_USER
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "3306"
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql

My mysql-storage.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi

My mysql-config.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql-config
  namespace: default
data:
  MYSQL_DB_NAME: testing001
  MYSQL_HOST: mysql
  MYSQL_PORT: "3306"
  MYSQL_USER: sean

Lastly my mysql-secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
data:
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: YWRtaW4K
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: YWRtaW4K


Where is the database running?  (Hopefully inside the cluster, in its own StatefulSet, with a matching Service?)  How have you configured your application to connect to the database?

Maybe this answer help you. https://serverfault.com/a/1141789/586657

I tried the solution to provided and I am still not able to connect to the DB.  But this does change the error message to "Access Denied".  This makes no sense as it works in the VM I've create but not my local.

I suppose then you run MySql in K8s it's ran usin non-root account. For example in Bitnami helm chart they use non-root user with ID 1001.
If you use a Helm chart for your K8s installation it must create MySql service. Create a port forward for port 3306 and connect to localhost:3306 from you local machine.
Documentation how to create port forward is here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/generated/kubectl_port-forward/

I have edited my post to include my yaml files.  Yes I have a service.  No I'm not using helm, and the service is of type clusterIP.  As I mentioned in my original question, I am connecting to the DB via command line directly in the container.
